# Are there any freely available resources to study randomized algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms

I am a student want to study randomized algorithm. Someone recommend [cs271](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Esinclair/cs271/s20.html) to me, but it's restricted now.

Can someone recomend a good resource to study randomized algorithm, thank you a lot.

Comment: https://archive.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days ago, my tutor recommend [Stanford cs265](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs265/#classes) to me. I have read some lectures and watched some videos, I think it's really a great course for those who want to study randomized algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you the book from Michael Mitzenmacher and Eli Upfal called "Probability and Computing". I bought a hard copy of it recently and I absolutely don't regret it. It's very detailed and goes through many different probabilistic tools along with important chapters from randomised algorithms.
It is complemented by various examples and some programming exercises. You can find a copy of it [here](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/spa/courses/uj16/mu-book.pdf)

Comment: Thank you a lot to offer the copy of this book, i will try to read it.

Comment: "This book is in copyright. Subject to statutory exception and to the provisions of relevant collective licensing agreements. no reproduction of any part may take place without the written permission of Cambridge University Press" @seboll13, have you checked the copyright notice?

Comment: @JohnL. since the book was on free access on the internet I believed it wasn’t a problem referencing it here. In any case, there is a second version (more recent of it) that is nowhere to be found on the internet. If it’s still a problem I can delete the answer.

Comment: Do you believe a second version removes the copyright of the previous version?

Comment: I believe that since the book is shared across a university website and is easily findable online, linking it won't result in copyright infringement.